# Optimal Insurance Coverage - risk neutral and risk loving consumers

Tags: finance, utility

I'm struggling with understanding a problem in finance:

We have 2 states:

$S_1$: bad state      $Y-K = 2000$; probability $\pi$ = 10%

$S_2$: normal state   $Y = 5000$;     probability $1-\pi$ = 90 %

If the insurance premium is $p = 0.2$, what would be the optimal amount of insurance $q$ for the following utility functions?

a) $u(x) = x$ (risk-neutral)

b) $u(x) = x^2$ [This one I find particularly tricky?] (risk-loving)

I know that we have to max $\pi \cdot u(Y-K+q-q \cdot p)+(1- \pi) \cdot u(Y-qp)$ and then take the derivative w.r.t. $q$ and set it equal to $0$ for risk-averse people, but how about these cases .

I also have the answers, but cannot figure out how exactly we reach them, so they are not so useful to me. ( a) $q=0$ or $q= -500$  if short sales are allowed; b) $q=22000$

I suppose that in both cases we would have a corner solution but at what value if at all this is true. I would be really grateful if somebody could explain this exercise to me :)

Best regards!

Comment: Is $v$ the same as the utility function $u$?

Comment: Yes, I just used another letter I guess, sorry for that.

Comment: are you sure you have to maximise the equation you given? since taking the derivative with the utility being linear leads to no expression for $q$ and thus you can set it to anything. the only thing you could do was set the whole thing to to be zero.

Comment: No, I am not sure, I think that we should maximize the equation in the case when the utility function is of risk-averse nature (e.g. u(x)=ln x). In that case it works fine and we can find the optimal coverage by taking the FOC and setting it equal to zero.

How we can calculate q in the cases of risk-neutral and risk-seeking functions is beyond me .. I think it should have something to do with the second order condition? I'm desperate.. :/

Comment: So the utility function for the first case is wrong in the post?

Comment: No, the utility functions in a) and b) are fine. That is why I am having a problem, because it is not the standard case of risk-aversion.

Comment: To be honest I am not too sure about the role of $K$ in this? Also, it seems the bad state occurs far less frequently than the good state and so becomes an issue as even a risk neutral person would still put more empathise on the good state. But I will watch this question though. :)

Comment: Well, K is the Loss that occurs in the bad state. The question is quite typical, I've seen it in many books and problem sets, however it is always with a risk-averse utility function... Thank you!